# How to proxy a checksum db

Tags: go, proxy

I have an internal go proxy running and I would like it to proxy a checksum database as well, as described [here](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25530-sumdb.md#proxying-a-checksum-database).

However, I do not know how to set up my client properly since the requests to the checksum database are not being forwarded to my internal proxy.
The environment variables in my client are like this

```
GONOPROXY=
GONOSUMDB=
GOPRIVATE=
GOPROXY=http://proxy.site
GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
```

I dump all http requests on my proxy, and I cannot see any requests for the checksum db.
These requests would be something like `http://proxy.site/sumdb/<endpoint>`.
However, my logs do not show anything.
When I set my GOSUMDB to any url other than sum.golang.org, then I get errors.
This shows that my client is indeed making requests to the checksum db, but not using the proxy, desping it being set.

Comment: With `GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org` checksum requests are sent to sum.golang.org, obviously. Which other values have you tried and which errors did you get, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The errors I got is irrelevant since you answered my question already: Having a proxy set in the client doesn't matter, the requests for the checksum db will not be sent to the proxy anyways (contrary to what I have seen https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25530-sumdb.md#proxying-a-checksum-database and https://docs.gomods.io/configuration/sumdb/).

Answer (score 0):

As Peter mentioned, requests are sent to the verifier key set in `GOSUMDB`, independent wheter a proxy is set or not.